# Matlab: Read an image process it and display the processed image

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I am new to Matlab.
I need to read an image from a file and process it. (i.e. read pixel values, resize it using my own functions,...) 
Then I need to display it on the UI. How do I do this?

IMSHOW() takes the whole axis area assigned and do not get resize.

**EDITED**
I get an image of 100X100px.
I want the user to see the 100X100px.
Then resize that image using my own function to 50X50px.
I want to show the resized image on the same axis, but this time it should be seen half of the original size.

Comment: I'm sorry this doesn't make any sense.  It sounds like you should display the whole image, but now you don't want to?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/displaying-images-using-the-imshow-function.html Adjusting the initial magnification may help; Also try this - http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/truesize.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want to do, the following should work for you

```
I=imread('path/to/file');
Ir=I(1:2:end,1:2:end); //resize 50%
```

This will **only** work for 50% resizing. Resizing at an arbitrary scale will need some interpolation.

The following will display the resized image on the upper left corner of the same figure:

```
imshow(I);
hold on;
imshow(Ir);
```

If I have not understood your purpose correctly let me know in the comments